# C++: How do you initialize an internal struct's members using an initialization list?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization

This is really two questions, noted below:

Currently I have some public internal helper structs (strictly used to pass data around as one object), during construction of an instance of the class I attempted to use initialization lists instead of assignment, but the compiler complained about the individual struct members so I added constructors to the structs...but that just seems like I'm headed down the wrong path.

**Is there a way to initialize a struct in an initializer list without using a constructor?**

**Would these helpers be better suited as an external class?**

```c
 
    class Foo {

    public:
    //...
        struct Bar {
            double mass;
            std::pair<double, double> gravMod;
            std::pair<double, double> position;
            std::pair<double, double> velocity;
            bool falling;
            Bar() : mass(0.0), gravMod(std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)), position(std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)), velocity(std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)), falling(false) { };
            Bar(double _mass, std::pair<double, double> _gravMod, std::pair<double, double> _position, std::pair<double, double> _velocity, bool _falling) 
             : mass(_mass), gravMod(_gravMod), position(_position), velocity(_velocity), falling(_falling) { }
            Bar(const Bar& other) 
                : mass(other.mass), gravMod(other.gravMod), position(other.position), velocity(other.velocity), falling(other.falling) { }
        };

        struct Baz {
            std::pair<double, double> acceleration;
            std::pair<double, double> force;
            Baz() : acceleration(std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)), force(std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)) { }
            Baz(std::pair<double, double> _acceleration, std::pair<double, double> _force) 
                : acceleration(_acceleration), force(_force) { }
            Baz(const Baz& other) : acceleration(other.acceleration), force(other.force) { }
        };

    //...
    protected:
    //...
    private:
        Bar _currBar;
        Bar _prevBar;
        Baz _currBaz;
        Baz _prevBaz;
    };
```

**EDIT**

Examples and their associated errors:

```c
 
Foo::Foo() : _currBar{0.0, std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0), std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0), std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0), false}, _currBaz{std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0), std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)} { }
```

`_currBar{` throws: `expected '('`. The first `}` throws: `expected';'`.

```c
 
Foo::Foo() : _currBar.mass(0.0), _currBar.gravMod(std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)), _currBar.position(std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)), _currBar.velocity(std::make_pair(0.0, 0.0)), _currBar.falling(false) { }
```

The first `_currBar.` throws: `expected '('`. All `_currBar.` afterwards throw `Member 'Foo::_currBar' has already been initialized.`.

Comment: "I added constructors to the structs...but that just seems like I'm headed down the wrong path."  That sounds like a fine path if you ask me...

Comment: Why do you think you're going down the wrong path with adding constructors?

Comment: How will you initialize members in every instance of those structs if not within the constructor?

Comment: What exactly was the compiler complaint? What don't you like about your code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++03, there is no way to initialize individual fields of a nested `struct`, nor is there a way to initialize individual fields of a nested array.  In C++0x (now C++11, I guess), they've relaxed this restriction and you can initialize nested `struct`s with a syntax like this:

```
Foo::Foo() : _currBar{fieldOneValue, fieldTwoValue, /* ... */, fieldNValue}, /* ... etc ... */
```

Adding constructors to your nested `struct`s is a perfectly viable option in the interim as we wait for more compilers to completely support this feature.

Comment: Array initialization syntax suggested does not work with VS2010 MSVC10. See edit for explanation.

Comment: @Casey- I never suggested that it did work.  The above code is in the proposed C++0x standard, which means that in a few years compilers will support it.  Until then, you'll have to put constructors in your helper structs to get this to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the approach you are using as long as you maintain the following:

> strictly used to pass data around as one object

When deciding whether to use a struct or a class the question to ask is: Does an *invariant* exist for this object? An invariant being a description of what constitutes a valid state for the object. If you can define an invariant, then it follows that you can also define an *invalid* state and that you should provide access to internal member variables only through member functions to ensure that a valid state can be maintained. This is best performed by a class. If, however, any old state will do; then use a struct.

Your constructors are merely giving sensible defaults and not attempting to maintain a valid state so there is nothing wrong with using them in a struct.

Answer (score 0):

You can in principle do without the constructors:

```
Foo::Foo(): _currBar(), _prevBar(), _currBaz(), _prevBaz() {}
```

This syntax zero-initializes a constructor-less object (sets all fields to 0 / invokes their default constructor).

If you want a constructor with parameters, you can use a helper function:

```
Bar make_bar(double mass, std::pair<double, double> gravMod, std::pair<double, double> position, std::pair<double, double> velocity, bool falling)
{
    Bar bar = { mass, gravMod, position, velocity, falling };
    return bar;
}

Foo::Foo(args...): _currBar(make_bar(args...)), ...
```

In any case, you don't need to add a copy constructor. The compiler will generate a copy constructor that will do exactly that.

(BTW, I probably wouldn't use `std::pair` when a math vector class would be more appropriate. I assume, things like `position` could rather use properties called `x` and `y` over `first` and `second`.)